# Using for loop in MySql data set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, plsql

How to use for loop in MySQL data set ?

```
FOR x IN (SELECT column FROM table_name WHERE column_2 = input_val) 
LOOP
    sum_total := sum_total + x.column ;
END LOOP;
```

This is an example how I used to loop data set in oracle.

How can this be achieved in MySql  ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about not looping at all. *It's SQL after all.*

```
SELECT SUM(`column`) total
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE column_2 = <input_val>
```

Otherwise use [`CURSOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

Now, equivalent loop using `CURSOR` will look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_loop(IN input_val INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE sum_current, sum_total INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT column1 FROM table_name WHERE column2 = input_val;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO sum_current;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET sum_total = sum_total + sum_current;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  SELECT sum_total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/192b6/3)**

Comment: I am not asking for alternative query, actually I want how the for loop actually works...anyway, thanks

Comment: +1 for encouraging set-based operations...Sql Engine is optimized for set based operation rather than cursor bsaed operation.....

Comment: @hsuk AFAIK you can achieve it in MySql only using cursor. See updated answer.

Comment: @hsuk Did it help after all?

Comment: Thanks bro,it helped but i was wondering if any thing else could be done other than using cursor

Comment: @hsuk You're very welcome :) I answered your follow up question right at the beginning of my answer. Use aggregate function(s) to instead of cursors. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `foo`.`usp_cursor_example`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `foo`.`usp_cursor_example`(
  IN name_in VARCHAR(255)
)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  DECLARE name_val VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE status_update_val VARCHAR(255);

  -- Declare variables used just for cursor and loop control
  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

  -- Declare the cursor
  DECLARE friends_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        name
      , status_update
    FROM foo.friend_status
    WHERE name = name_in;

  -- Declare 'handlers' for exceptions
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;


  OPEN friends_cur;
  select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

  the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH  friends_cur
    INTO   name_val
    ,      status_update_val;


    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE friends_cur;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    select name_val, status_update_val;

    -- count the number of times looped
    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;

  END LOOP the_loop;

  -- 'print' the output so we can see they are the same
  select num_rows, loop_cntr;

END
DELIMITER ;
```